# Can we access archive mailbox (In Place archived) using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access Archive Mailbox (In Place archived) , using MS Graph API , but found that its not working.

Does MsGraph support it ? If not then whats the other programatic way to get this content? Any other API?

Comment: AppPerfect ka employee hai kya bro?

Answer (score 1):

No InPlace Archives aren't currently accessible using the Graph API, you can access them using EWS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth then something like this would list the folder in the Archive

```
        FolderView fv = new FolderView(1000);
        FindFoldersResults ffResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.ArchiveMsgFolderRoot, fv);
```